# Guardar texto en bloc de notas sin reemplazar el anterior, Python

Tags: python

Buen dia, Mi pregunta es la misma del titulo.

Si con esto reemplazo y guardo un texto. Como podría hacer para que no se borre?

```
 file = open("caps.txt","w")
 file.write("No quiero reemplazar")
 file.close()
```

Comment: cambia a `file = open("caps.txt","a")`

Comment: @Luke Tan simple, Gracias.